# Update the file sent in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I wrote a program that uploads a series of data to firebase
My problem is that when new data is uploaded, the previous contents of the file in Firebase are deleted and new data is replaced.
It is possible to guide the previous data to be added to the new data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbODa.png)

```
            String key_press ="key pressed :"+sb;





        reference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Dcument");
        reference.child("file.txt").putBytes(sb.toString().getBytes()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
               // Toast.makeText(MyAccessibilityService.this, "file upload seuccessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MyAccessibilityService.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you explain more about ```file.txt``` ? you need to override with different file name ```(file1.txt,file2.txt . . . )``` ?

Comment: Hossein is the name of the file in which we save the existing data, and any name can be used for the file name.

Answer (score 1):

When you write data to a path in Cloud Storage (with Firebase or any of the other SDKs) it replaces any data that existed at that path. There is no way to tell Cloud Storage to merge the data, as it treats all files/objects as blobs and doesn't have any knowledge about the file's structure.

So you will either have to read the existing data, merge that with your update, and then write the result to Cloud Storage, or store the new data as a separate file in Cloud Storage.

Comment: Can you guide me with the source code how to save the data in different files?

Comment: This is what determines the file name on Cloud Storage: `reference.child("file.txt")`. So if you want a different name, use a different value there. If you can't think of specific value, you could number the files incrementally.